# How to dynamically display value of a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am having 3 radio buttons approved and rejected and 4 text fields and text boxes..

If i am clicking r1, all the text field and text boxes should be hided. but if i am clicking r2 and r3 the text field and text box should be displayed..

This is the code which i have used

> if(approved.checked == true) {
>
> ```
>   reason.style.visibility="hidden";
>
>   Reason.style.visibility="hidden";
>   sanction.style.visibility="display";
>   sanctioned.style.visibility="display";
> }
>
> if(rejected.checked == true) {
>     reason.disabled =false;
>   reason.style.display="none";
>   Reason.style.display="none";
>   sanction.style.visibility="hidden";
>   sanctioned.style.visibility="hidden";
> }
> ```

This code is working for the first time when i click those radio buttons. But if am clicking rejected and then clicking approved it is not working.

Comment: Please try to use the formatting tool when posting code samples. (fixed it for you this time) :]

Comment: Hmm. `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` are not completely analogous. I'd use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @TiesonT. I tried without using display:none also. Even then it was not working

Comment: The title is no way related to the question you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix the *display* and *visibility* properties, use one or the other. [Valid values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html) for the display property are: inline | block | list-item | inline-block | table | inline-table | table-row-group | table-header-group | table-footer-group | table-row | table-column-group | table-column | table-cell | table-caption | none | inherit

Valid values for visibility are: visible | hidden | collapse | inherit

The short answer: use *visible* instead of *display*.

So your code can be (assuming the variables are references to suitable DOM elements):

```
if(approved.checked) {
  reason.disabled = true;   // keep symetry with next loop
  reason.style.visibility = "hidden";
  Reason.style.visibility = "hidden";
  sanction.style.visibility = "visible";
  sanctioned.style.visibility = "visible";
}

if(rejected.checked) {
  reason.disabled = false;
  reason.style.visibility = "hidden";
  Reason.style.visibility  = "hidden";
  sanction.style.visibility = "hidden";
  sanctioned.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Note that it is simpler to hide the form controls by putting them inside another element (say a div) and hiding that. But why not just disable them? Hiding and showing them might annoy, distract or just plain confuse users.

Comment: This is working fine. Thanks for your valuable quick suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

in the first instead of reason.style.visibility="hidden you can  use a jQuery function .hide()
and .show(),

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
            if (this.id == r1) { 
                $('#textes').hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#textes').shwo();
            }
        })
        if (approved.checked == true)

    })
</script>

<div id="textes">
/*your chack  text fields and text boxes..*/
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rEK87/1/

Comment: in my answer I use jQuery, do you know jQuery?

Comment: I have not yet used jQuery. So if you could give up with a solution in JavaScript that would be greatfull..

Answer (score 0):

Per your examples and our comments above, is this what you are after?

**Markup:**

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="rdo" id="r1" />
    <label for="r1">Approved</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdo" id="r2" />
    <label for="r2">Rejected</label>
</form>
<div id="accepted">
    <p>This is the accepted block.</p>
</div>
<div id="rejected">
    <p>This is the rejected block.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#accepted, #rejected
{
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#r1').click(function(e){
        $('#accepted').show();
        $('#rejected').hide();
    }); 

        $('#r2').click(function(e){
        $('#accepted').hide();
        $('#rejected').show();
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rEK87/